# how to identify the element that was clicked?

Tags: javascript, jquery

please help to fix the [script](http://jsfiddle.net/hfoeja7f/).

after the user clicks on an item .menu_button, there is a call function initForm(). This function should print one

```
console.log(N)
```

but displays 3:

```
console.log(1)
console.log(2)
console.log(3)
```

I do not understand

js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // --- PLUGIN kalininModals INITIALIZATION ---
    $('.menu_button').kalininModals();
);

(function($){
    // --- options ---  
    $.fn.kalininModals = function(options) {                    
        var options = $.extend({},options);

        return this.each(function(e) {
            // --- properties ---   
            var self = $(this),
                selfModals = $('#modalOuter'),
                selfModalsWindow = $('#modalWindow'),
                head,
                info,
                actionsArr; 

            // --- methods ---  
            function initForm(formNum){
                //console.log('___' + self.text());

                if(formNum == 1){
                    console.log(1);

                    head = 'Обратный звонок';


                }
                else if(formNum == 2){
                    console.log(2);

                    head = 'Обратный звонок';


                }
                else if(formNum == 3){
                    console.log(3);

                    head = 'Обратный звонок';
                };          
            }

            function makeBody(){
                console.log('make');

                $('#head .h2').text(head);
                $('#info').html(info);
            }




            // --- handlers ---     
            function onClickControls(e){
                self = $(e.currentTarget);
                initForm(self.attr('data-form-num'));
                makeBody();

            }

            // --- events ---
            $('#menuButton1, #menuButton2, #menuButton3').on('click', onClickControls); 

        });
    };
})($);
```

Comment: on ln374 you have `return this.each(function(e) {` which initialized the code for hanlding click event three times, as `this` is an array with the three menu elements.

Comment: makes no sense to apply a plugin to a group of elements, then have click handlers applied within the plugin to a hard coded collection of selectors that represent the same elements. The click handler is being added as many times as there are elements in the initial collection

Comment: in other words remove the initilization code from the `each` function, this is an example of the same code without the `each` function http://jsfiddle.net/302x0u2e/1  (not sure it the `each` was required somewhere).

Answer (score -1):

make use of class

```
<div class="menuButton">Menu 1</div>
<div class="menuButton">Menu 2</div>
<div class="menuButton">Menu 3</div>
```

and in jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".menuButton").click(function(){
        alert($(this).html());
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: this in no way resolves the problem of the plugin code